# CalendarListEntry not showing up with Google PHP API

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I am trying to add an entry with this sample of code :

```
<?php

$service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarListEntry = new \Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry();
$calendarListEntry->setId($calendarId);
$calendarListEntry->setHidden(false);
$calendarListEntry->setSelected(true);
$calendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->insert($calendarListEntry);
```

The calendar is inserted but not shown on the Gmail Android App. I have to go to settings to display it.

I thought with `setHidden()` and `setSelected()` it would work but it didn't change anything. Plus, `$calendarListEntry` returned after insert has `hidden = null`.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: I think your code is working fine. By default, when [adding an entry](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert#examples) to the user's calendar list using [`calendarListEntry`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/#calendar_vs_calendarList), it is visible to the list or the default value of hidden is False. `selected` parameter shows whether the calendar content shows up in the **calendar UI**. Optional. The default is False. Try using the Calendar Android App to confirm your entry is added.

Comment: The entry is added on the Calendar Android App but the user has to go into settings to display it. Do you think it would be possible to bypass this ?